# Excel waiting on mail client

Tags: excel, email, outlook, client, attachment

We have been using a very basic VBA script in an Excel workbook that opens a new email and adds the workbook as an attachment.  In the script, it also copies a small section of workbook and we paste it as a picture in the email.  It has worked on a variety of machines with no issue for two years.  One of our users has a new PC.  When she tried to execute the script, she was unable to paste the picture in the email.  Excel is disabled until Outlook completes it's task.  It does this prior to the copy command, so there is nothing to copy into the email.  I've looked through the options on both Excel and Outlook, but I don't see anything different between the new machine and her old one.

I know it's nothing with the code, as it has worked on all of our machines in the past.  In any case, I have copied it below.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
Sub SendEmail()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Daily Cash")

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show

ws.Range("B2:H18").Copy

Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This code pastes?

Comment: No...we just right click and paste as picture once the email opens.  But that is the problem we have now.  On her machine, Excel is waiting on Outlook to complete it's task.  It can't get to the "ws.Range("B2:H18").Copy" because it's getting hung up on the previous line.  I'm just not sure why it's only her machine that is impacted by this.